# Calling individual Divs by id from PHP generated list using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am generating divs in PHP, from an array, thus:

```
echo "<div id='parentdiv'>";
 for($counter = 0; $counter < count($list); $counter++){
         echo "<div>".$list['important_info']."</div>";

   }
  echo "</div>";//parentdiv
```

I want to add some click functionality to each div independently, i.e. the action performed on clicking depends on the div, and more importantly the index of the array, $list;

I want to give each div an id based on it's index in the PHP array.
 So I could do

```
echo "<div id='"."divindex_".$counter."'>".$list['important_info']."</div>";
```

where "divindex_" is just used to prevent the id form beginning with a numeric value.

Then, I think in jQuery I can write click functions for each div.

However the problem is the $list size is variable, so I don't know how many divs there are. 
So what I'm thinking is something like,

```
 $("#parentdiv div").click(function(){
            var id = split($(this).attr('id').split("_")[1];//get the php index from the id
            //do something with the id, e.g. ajax or whatever
　　});
```

Is there a better way to do this? If you think what I'm doing is strange and not a very good idea, then I understand. But I don't know how to do this any other way. Any help appreciated.

Comment: +1 for the well-explained question!

Comment: Does `$list` have a unique key in which you need to use for your `ajax or whatever` functionality

Comment: @DickieBoy Yep, it is necessary to know the index values for database inserts.

Comment: Then the answer you have checked as correct will only work if all the unique keys are the 1-X. If you have 7 records. and record number 5 gets deleted. The `$counter` will go up to 6 with one div having a parsed id of 5 which would cause your ajax request with id to fail.

Comment: Well, the scope of my question is specific to my case as the records should never get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
$("#parentdiv div").click(function(){
            var id  = $(this).index(); //index of div, 0 based
            var val = $(this).text();  //content of div, if you need it
});
```

No need to add unique `ID`s :) .

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/q9TaJ/

Docs:
http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to properly escape your outputs:

```
echo '<div id="parentdiv">';
for ($counter = 0; $counter < count($list); $counter++){
    echo sprintf('<div data-id="%d">%s</div>',
        $counter,
        htmlspecialchars($list['important_info'])
    );
}
echo '</div>';//parentdiv
```

I'm also using a special attribute called `data-id` which you can easily access in jQuery with this code:

```
$('#parentdiv > div').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

Comment: I went with another answer, but this answer was very interesting. Didn't know about data-id. +1'd you

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your variables as html attributes. Then bind the click event to a single class.

```
<div class="divs" data-id="myid"></div>
```

in jquery

```
 $('.divs').click(function(){
console.log($(this).data('id));    
});
```